# Weighted Average in Stata's collapse command

Tags: stata

I couldn't find a Stata command on the following issue, so I solved it manually:

According to the official manual, Stata doesn't do weights with averages in the collapse command (p. 6 of the [Collapse](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/dcollapse.pdf) chapter):

[image]

It means that I am not able to get weighted average prices paid in my sales data set at a week/product level where the weight is the units sold. The data set is a collection of single transactions with # of purchases and prices per unit paid at week/store/product level:

```
clear
set more off
week,store,product,price,units
1,1,cheer,1,10
1,1,tide,2,6
1,2,cheer,2,7
1,2,tide,3,5
2,1,cheer,1,15
2,1,tide,1,20
2,1,mrclean,2,8
2,2,cheer,2,8
2,2,tide,4,5
2,2,mrclean,3,4
```

Clearly, taking simple averages when collapsing ignores number of units purchased, resulting in a wrong average price estimate.

So what I did is I manually calculated a new variable `price x units` in the original data set. Then, I collapsed the dataset by summing up the `price x units` and `units` variables:

```
collapse (sum) pricexunits units, by(week product)
```

And finally,  I created a new variable where I divided `pricexunits` by `units`. Do you think I could have done something differently?

Answer (score 2):

You're misreading that documentation.

The point is whether *normalization* makes a difference to the results for different kinds of weights, not whether weights are allowed at all. In fact, weights are fairly generally allowed, as the help and manual entry explain.

Thus, the frequency-weighted sum or count differs from the analytically-weighted sum or count, and so forth.

Weights are allowed with `collapse (mean)`. Try it, e.g.

```
collapse (mean) price [w=units] , by(week product)
```

Comment: Does it allow to apply the command [w=units] only to a specific portion of the code, i.e. (mean) price? So that if I have other combinations of commands and variables, it will not affect them?

Comment: I can't see examples of the code you intend. Why not try it with toy examples where you can work out what the answer should be? You would be told promptly if any combination were not allowed.

Comment: The documentation and a few tests suggest that the weights apply to all operations in the collapse command, and that only one set of weights is possible per command.

Comment: @ASV You're correct. I wasn't implying otherwise. The spirit of my comment was intended to be "Come on, you can work this out". Anyone who wants to say more is always welcome.